# How can I alter discussion settings dynamically for certain custom post types

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a way to alter the behaviour of comments for a custom post type.

Comments for other post types should be allowed without user login – and that's how it's been set up on the admin panel Discussion settings. However for one particular custom post type I want to enforce that users must be logged in to comment on that post type.

I'm guessing that the way to do this is to alter the discussion settings dynamically before calling `custom_form()` but I can't find any documentation on how to do that.

The other option would be a way to set this setting in the admin panel but only for this custom post-type.

Is either of these things possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update_option('comment_registration',true);
custom_form()
```